# Construction logic for Hierarchial tree in Recursion fashion

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, recursion, mxgraph

[image]

```
var cellData = [];
function constructCells(graph, cell) {
  var cellDataObj = {};
  var outgoingEdges = graph.getOutgoingEdges(cell);
  cellDataObj.id = cell.id;
  cellDataObj.value = cell.value;

  if (outgoingEdges.length) {
    cellDataObj.children = [];
    _.each(outgoingEdges, vertex => {
      const target = vertex.target;
      var targetEdges = graph.getOutgoingEdges(target);
      if (targetEdges.length) {
        cellDataObj.children.push({
          id: target.id,
          value: target.value,
          children: getChildrens(graph, target)
        });
      } else {
        cellDataObj.children.push({ id: target.id, value: target.value });
      }
    });
  }
  cellData.push(cellDataObj);
}

function getChildrens(graph, cell) {
  var cells = [];
  var outgoingEdges = graph.getOutgoingEdges(cell);
  _.each(outgoingEdges, vertex => {
    cells.push({
      id: vertex.target.id,
      value: vertex.target.value
    });
  });
  return cells;
}
```

The above code works pretty well till first and second level i.e till v3 node and it constructs v4 and v5 as its childrens. But i am losing the logic somewhere here and not able to construct for below nodes if that holds children.

The result is:
[image]

> Looking forward for logic correction required for multilevel nesting
>   i.e for the level of V6 and V7 level nodes.

You can consider the below images for the reference of what is expected:

[image]

Flat to json conversion, sorry, i am not able to post the code as the consists of library data and code needs to be cleaned up.

[image]

Comment: There's no recursion in your code, that's what you're missing. Neither `constructCells` nor `getChildrens` calls itself. Also please post your objects (result, expected result) as **text**.

Comment: According to requirement, we only construct children’s array if there are edges associated. Hence this could be n number of levels as well. I fee it should be recursive and I can’t restrict the levels. Correct me if am wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To go from a flat list to a tree, you don't need recursion. The other way around, it does make sense.

---

Here's how to get from a flat list to a nested structure using a single loop:

- Create an empty object for storing nodes by their id
- Create an empty object for storing nodes that appear *before* we've handled their parent
- Go over all entries

  - Create a node
  - Check if we've seen nodes referencing this id as their parent before

    - If we did, pre-fill the children array with those nodes
  - Add the node to an object using its id as a key
  - Check if the object already includes the node's parent

    - If it does, push the new node to its parent children array
    - If it does not, index the node as a temporary orphan
  - Check if the node is the root node, and store it if so
- return the root node

In code:

```js
const flat = [
  { id: 1, parentId: 3 },
  { id: 3, parentId: 8 },
  { id: 4, parentId: 6 },
  { id: 6, parentId: 3 },
  { id: 7, parentId: 6 },
  { id: 8, parentId: null },
  { id: 10, parentId: 8 },
  { id: 13, parentId: 14 },
  { id: 14, parentId: 10 }
];

const toTree = nodes => {
  const index = {};
  const orphans = {};
  let root = null;
  
  nodes.forEach(
    ({ id, parentId }) => {
      const node = { id, children: orphans[id] || [] };
      index[id] = node;

      const parent = index[parentId];
      
      if (!parent) {
        if (orphans[parentId]) orphans[parentId].push(node)
        else orphans[parentId] = [node];
      } else {
        parent.children.push(node);
      }

      if (parentId === null) root = node;
    }
  );
  
  return root;
}
  

console.log(JSON.stringify(toTree(flat), null, 2));
```

---

To go back to a flat list:

- Call `flatten` starting with the root node
- Concatenate the root node to a result array
- If it has children, flatten each of them using the root node id as a parent id (i.e. recurse)

```js
const tree = {"id":8,"children":[{"id":3,"children":[{"id":1,"children":[]},{"id":6,"children":[{"id":4,"children":[]},{"id":7,"children":[]}]}]},{"id":10,"children":[{"id":14,"children":[{"id":13,"children":[]}]}]}]};

const flatten = (node, parentId = null) => 
  [{ id: node.id, parentId }].concat(
    node.children.flatMap(
      child => flatten(child, node.id)
    )
  );
    
console.log(flatten(tree));
```